# Excel lookups and multiple criteria including next highest match

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I need to use the Table1 table to find the pressure loss per pipe size and flow rate.  The below method works well if there is there is an exact match but I need the match on Flow rate to be exact or else the next biggest size.

Its finding the next biggest size, but cant get it to return the next biggest size for the relevant pipe size.

=(FILTER(Table1[PresureLoss],(Table1[PipeSize]=B20)*(Table1[FlowRate]=(INDEX(Presure!A:C,XMATCH(A20,Presure!C:C,1,1),3)))))*C20

Link to file is below.

[image]

[image]

https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArK27D6mARyCgZMEjBVQbGeeRn3CzQ?e=19DJWv

Comment: So use an if() to repeat that expression but with the pipe size increased by 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would filter pressure loss and flow rate by pipe size first, then use Xlookup like this:

```
=XLOOKUP(A20,FILTER(Table1[FlowRate],Table1[PipeSize]=B20),FILTER(Table1[PresureLoss],Table1[PipeSize]=B20),,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I was heading in that direction but going nowhere!  That now works perfectly.